# POST data to server using AngularJS (ionic framework)

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, ionic-framework

I'm trying to post data to a server from my ionic app. The URL to use is in a variable. Here is what I tried:

First I've created a service like this:

```
.service('PostTuto', ['$http',function($http) {
    this.servicioPostTuto = function(tema,ubicacion,horario,nom_coe) {
      return $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://"""""".""".""""."""":8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/insert?apikey=3bff8615827f32442199fdb2ed4df4&trama={"Nombre":"'+tema+'","Apellido":"'+ubicacion+'","Sexo":"'+horario+'","Residencia":"'+nom_coe+'"}',
            });
    };
}])
```

in this part I send in my url the variables `tema`, `ubicacion`, `horario`, `nom_coe` and my controller. I've done this:

```
$scope.data = {}; 
  $scope.create=function(){
    $scope.nom_coe="IDfromSubject"
    PostTuto.servicioPostTuto($scope.data.tema,$scope.data.ubicacion,$scope.data.horario,$scope.nom_coe)
    .success(function(data){
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'created'
      });
    })
    .error(function(data){
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Error to post data'
      });
    });
  };
  //FIN POSTEAR DATOS A SERVIDOR
```

In this part I receive the data from input in my html file.

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label"><strong>Tema:</strong></span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.tema" ng-disabled="editar">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label"><strong>Ubicacion:</strong></span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.ubicacion" ng-disabled="editar">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label"><strong>Horario:</strong></span>
          <input type="text" ng-model="data.horario" ng-disabled="editar">
        </label>
        <a class="button button-block icon-left ion-ios-compose button-positive" 
          ng-disabled="!data.tema || !data.ubicacion || !data.horario" ng-click="create()">
          create
        </a>
```

When I try to post data, my app returns me an error "Error to post data", how can I fix that?

Comment: can you check your webservice from postman it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sending your API key in querystring is not a good way.You could try this

In Controller Js

```
$scope.data=new Object();

$scope.create=function(){
PostTuto.servicioPostTuto($scope.data)
 .success(function(data){
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'created'
  });
})
.error(function(data){
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
    title: 'Error to post data'
  });
});
};
```

And in your AppConfig.js

```
app.run(function($http){
            $http.defaults.headers.common['APIKey'] = "3bff8615827f32442199fdb2ed4df4";
})
```

And in your service

```
.service('PostTuto', ['$http',function($http) {
     this.servicioPostTuto = function(data) {
     return $http.post('http://"""""".""".""""."""":8080/smartlandiotv2/webresources/entidades.datos/insert',data);
     }

}])
```

Now from serverside ,you could get your APIKey from Request header for your purpose